# International Trash Mountain

Tags: mountains, waste

How high would trash mountains be if all the trash was piled into 1 continent like Antarctica?
[image]
https://michielkauwatjoe.com/images/works/trash-mountain-michielkauwatjoe.com-large.jpg

Comment: If all the trash from the city of Karakorum (Genghis Khan's capital city) for the last 500 years were piled up it would reach a height of..... 0 inches. The continent of Antarctica probably has the lowest trash footprint, Not sure about the worst. Could you please just ask one question as per the [help] rules, and make it specific enough to be answerable? VTC. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: This is not a WB question - it sounds more like an environmental issue.

Comment: It decomposes into liquids that pollute aquifers. It's highly unstable and tends to collapse (should not be too steep) . Organic matter deep inside will release methane and odorous sulfur compounds. Solution: Sort and recycle!

Comment: Our [help/on-topic] explains that questions **must** be specific (check!) **and** answerable (*maybe*), **must** include context (missing), **must** include restrictions (missing) and requirements (missing), and *should* include research (missing).

Comment: You accepted an answer but your edit plainly invalidates it.

Comment: An accepted answer means it solved your problem. An edited question means you are rephrasing your problem statement. An accepted answer followed by an edited question... what does it say?

Comment: Accepting an answer is not mandatory. Attaching images is not mandatory.

Comment: @L.Dutch I will try harder.

Comment: @L.Dutch Images helps me illustrate my thoughts where words cannot. I like illustrations in my books.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Piling trash next to cities has been done, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Trashmore_Park and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Trashmore_(Florida) It's much more common to put it in a hole - AKA landfill - and cover it.

The problem with piling all the trash of a continent in one place is obviously the cost (and environmental effects) of transporting it.  You could calculate the cost yourself by finding estimates of how much trash is generated by your continent, picking a location, and looking up ton-mile transport costs.

Comment: I'm sorry for changing the question if there is anything you can do to make it better I will be grateful.